# Cloning Win10 Home to Win10 Pro laptop

Tags: windows-10, disk-cloning

So I have a new work laptop with Windows 10 Pro installed that I need to make ready for my use.

My previous just-a-little-too-crashy (for hardware reasons! probably...) work laptop already has all the large things I'll need (Office, two versions of Visual Studio, various SDKs, the horde of other things I've forgotten) downloaded and installed and nicely configured and I *excessively* hate redoing all of that.  So I'd really like to just clone its drive to the new laptop, but it's unfortunately running Windows 10 *Home*.

Now, I don't really need Pro's features, and the seductive claims of Acronis Universal Restore combined with my prior experience successfully cloning Windows to radically different hardware means I'm not concerned about hardware problems, either (even if I should be).

What *does* worry me is the possible licensing issue I see arising.  Will my new laptop's Windows 10 *Pro* license (which I understand is effectively "baked in" to its hardware) satisfy the installation of Windows 10 *Home* that would be moving in?  Has anyone else tried this before (with or without my silly reasons)?

Comment: "Will my new laptop's Windows 10 Pro license (which I understand is effectively "baked in" to its hardware) satisfy the installation of Windows 10 Home that would be moving in? " - No.  A Windows 10 Home license can only activate a Windows 10 Home installation.  Any other version the license key will be rejected.  This doesn't mean you cannot copy your current installation, and simply upgrade the cloned installation to Windows 10 Professional.

Comment: @Ramhound Microsoft appears to confirms your statement on [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12384/windows-10-upgrading-home-to-pro), with these words:
"If you already installed and activated Windows 10 Pro on your device, you'll have a digital entitlement that lets you upgrade from Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Pro without a product key."

Gonna give it a try, then.

Comment: Once you have Home installed you can use the generic key to perform the upgrade, and after you connect your local profile on the new machine to a Microsoft account, it will perform the entitlement activation.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried it and it all worked as [Microsoft describes here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12384/windows-10-upgrading-home-to-pro).

**Specifically:**
After booting into Windows 10 Home on the new laptop, I went to Settings > Update & security > Activation > Troubleshoot. A diagnostic thing started and quickly detected the laptop's digital license for Windows 10 Pro and offered to upgrade; which I accepted.  After that and the hours of Windows Updates, everything is working swell so far!